# Custom Loss Function of Keras Model Giving Incorrect Answer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to write a custom loss function for a keras NN model, but it seems like the loss function is outputting the wrong value. My loss function is

```
def tangle_loss3(input_tensor):
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        true_diff = y_true - input_tensor
        pred_diff = y_pred - input_tensor
        
        normalized_diff = K.abs(tf.math.divide(pred_diff, true_diff))
        normalized_diff = tf.reduce_mean(normalized_diff)
        
        return normalized_diff
    
    return custom_loss
```

Then I use it in this simple feed-forward network:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(384,), name='input')
hl_1 = Dense(64, activation='elu', name='hl_1')(input_layer)
hl_2 = Dense(32, activation='elu', name='hl_2')(hl_1)
hl_3 = Dense(32, activation='elu', name='hl_3')(hl_2)
output_layer = Dense(384, activation=None, name='output')(hl_3)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, output_layer)
model.compile(loss=tangle_loss3(input_layer), optimizer=optimizer)
```

Then to test whether the loss function is working, I created a random input and target vector and did the numpy calculation of what I expect, but this does not seem to match the result from keras.

```
X = np.random.rand(1, 384)
y = np.random.rand(1, 384)

np.mean(np.abs((model.predict(X) - X)/(y - X)))
# returns some number 

model.test_on_batch(X, y)
# always returns 0.0
```

Why does my loss function always return zero? And should these answers match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood your issue, and I have updated my method. it should work now. I stack the input layer and output layer to get a new layer that I pass to output.

```py
    def tangle_loss3(y_true, y_pred):
        true_diff = y_true - y_pred[0]
        pred_diff = y_pred[1] - y_pred[0]
    
        normalized_diff = tf.abs(tf.math.divide(pred_diff, true_diff))
        normalized_diff = tf.reduce_mean(normalized_diff)
    
        return normalized_diff

    input_layer = Input(shape=(384,), name='input')
    hl_1 = Dense(64, activation='elu', name='hl_1')(input_layer)
    hl_2 = Dense(32, activation='elu', name='hl_2')(hl_1)
    hl_3 = Dense(32, activation='elu', name='hl_3')(hl_2)
    output_layer = Dense(384, activation=None, name='output')(hl_3)
    out = tf.stack([input_layer, output_layer])
    
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, out)
    model.compile(loss=tangle_loss3, optimizer=optimizer)
```

and now when I calculate the loss it works

```py
    X = np.random.rand(1, 384)
    y = np.random.rand(1, 384)
    
    np.mean(np.abs((model.predict(X)[1] - X)/(y - X)))
    # returns some number
    
    model.test_on_batch(X, y)
```

Note that I have to use model.predict(X)[1] as we get two outputs, both the input and output layers' results. This is just one hacky solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The custom loss works well with single non-nested `custom_loss(y_true,y_pred)`. You can try to add [Subtract](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/subtract/) layer of keras for output and then try to use new label as `new_label = label - input` right before you add to to the training pipeline.

Now only use customloss